# Not able to quit when condition is met in python

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I am trying to make a tic tac toe game in python3. I am able to get the game working, but when somebody has won the game, Ì am unable to get the code to terminate. I tried a a lot of methods but none are working:

```
def find_winner(board,gameIsOn): 
if ((board[7]==board[8]==board[9]) and board[7]!= '') or ((board[4]==board[5]==board[6]) and board[4]!= '') or ((board[1]==board[2]==board[3]) and board[7]!= ''):
    gameIsOn = False
    print('winner!')


elif ((board[7]==board[4]==board[1]) and board[7]!= '') or ((board[8]==board[5]==board[2]) and board[8]!= '') or ((board[9]==board[6]==board[3]) and board[9]!= ''):
    gameIsOn = False
    print('winner!')


elif ((board[7]==board[5]==board[3]) and board[7]!= '') or ((board[9]==board[5]==board[1]) and board[7]!= ''):

    gameIsOn = False
    print('winner!')
```

this is the function I used to find out if somebody has won. the `gameIsOn` variable is set to `False` if somebody has won. Otherwise it is `True`.

```
while(gameIsOn):
if(active_Player == player_1):
        position = int(input('Position?'))
        player_input(board,active_Player,position)
        print_board(board)
        find_winner(board,gameIsOn)
        active_Player = player_2           
else:
        position = int(input('Position?'))
        player_input(board,active_Player,position)
        print_board(board)
        find_winner(board,gameIsOn)**
```

The above code is the body of the game. Ignoring the other functions, the `find_winner` function should set the value of `gameIsOn` to `False`, if somebody has won the game. But the game is not terminating even after somebody has won.

Can someone please help?

Comment: btw is this also not indented in you own code?

Comment: it is indented. I didnt know how to indent it properly in stackexchange. my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the `gameIsOn` variable to the `find_winner` function and it becomes a local variable there so the changes to `gameIsOn` do not get reflected to the caller. You should make find_winner return the Boolean value to the caller and have the caller assign the returning value to the `gameIsOn` variable in its scope instead.

```
def find_winner(board):
    if ((board[7]==board[8]==board[9]) and board[7]!= '') or ((board[4]==board[5]==board[6]) and board[4]!= '') or ((board[1]==board[2]==board[3]) and board[7]!= ''):
        return False

    elif ((board[7]==board[4]==board[1]) and board[7]!= '') or ((board[8]==board[5]==board[2]) and board[8]!= '') or ((board[9]==board[6]==board[3]) and board[9]!= ''):
        return False

    elif ((board[7]==board[5]==board[3]) and board[7]!= '') or ((board[9]==board[5]==board[1]) and board[7]!= ''):
        return False
    return True

gameIsOn = True
while(gameIsOn):
    if(active_Player == player_1):
        position = int(input('Position?'))
        player_input(board,active_Player,position)
        print_board(board)
        gameIsOn = find_winner(board)
        active_Player = player_2           
    else:
        position = int(input('Position?'))
        player_input(board,active_Player,position)
        print_board(board)
        gameIsOn = find_winner(board)
        active_Player = player_1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `sys.exit()` and `exit()`